# CTRL Keys not working in Samsung Ultra Book

Tags: keyboard

Both my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are not working on Ubuntu 19.04
When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with my external keyboard its working fine.

I don't whether this is a hardware fault or my laptop being very old (Samsung Ultra book series 5). I recently got it, repaired and installed Ubuntu on it.

How can I solve this issue, or can you help me figure out whether if it's a hardware fault or software ?

Comment: I would try using `xev` to see if any input is seen when you press the keys; I can't advise more than that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a complete answer; as I have none. However

I'd start exploring your keyboard input using `xev` to see if the key is recognized by your OS.

Second to confirm it's not a problem with your installed Ubuntu 19.04 system, I would boot a 'live' distro (*I'd go for something very different myself; different kernel, maybe even a non-debian based OS*) and repeat the same tests there.   My hope is it'll confirm it's not a setup/config issue with your current OS/release or settings.

Compare the `xev` findings of the live' OS with your installed Ubuntu 19.04 to see if different.  If they are the same, it's far more likely a hardware issue.

Comment: i just remapped control key to menu key thnx anyway. I think its a hardware issue